# Dual Boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04 Problems

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-7

I have been looking into dual booting Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit with Windows 7 Professional 64 bit and  have been running into issues with Ubuntu's installer not detecting the Windows 7 installation. Here is what I have read and tried.

Relevant Computer Details:
i7-4500U
8 GB RAM
256 GB SSD

Installation Process (this worked for me before on a different laptop):
1. Booted using Windows installation disk, deleted all the partitions and then made 1 209 GB partition for Windows and another for Ubuntu. 
2. Installed Windows 
3. Tried to install Ubuntu but it could not locate the Windows 7

Tried to do

```
$ sudo apt-get install gdisk
$ sudo fixparts /dev/sda
and then press the key 'w'
```

as read in another post but that didn't do anything. I still had the same problem. An interesting note is that I got the message "Warning:0xEE partition doesn't start on sector 1. This can cause problems in some OSes" when I ran fixparts. Looked it up on google and it seemed fairly irrelevant. If it is relevant please let me know.

After I did that, Ubuntu installer still wouldn't find the windows 7 OS.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to be careful not to mix UEFI & BIOS and gpt and MBR(msdos) partitioning. YOur system is a new UEFI based system, but Windows 7 default install is BIOS with MBR partitioning. So if you did not install Windows 7 in UEFI mode, you must be sure to install Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode. And use fixparts to remove any gpt data if drive was ever gpt as Windows does not correctly convert it. Post theses: sudo parted -l AND sudo fdisk -lu.

Comment: I tried to find whether my bios is UEFI based or BIOS based and it seems like it's BIOS. I followed the steps mentioned here <http://kb.parallels.com/en/115815> and was returned the following : Callback_BootEnvironmentDetect: Detected boot environment: BIOS. How did you know my system is UEFI based? Also, do you have any pointers to installing Ubuntu in BIOS boot mode?

Comment: Here are the results to sudo parted -l and sudo fdisk -lu http://tinypic.com/r/2u76q28/8

Comment: Better to just post output in you original question above. But you just have to partitions and a standard Windows BIOS boot with MBR partitions. You mentioned gdisk which really is for gpt partitioned drives and Windows only boots from gpt drives with UEFI. http://www.rodsbooks.com/missing-parts/index.html

Comment: Alright so is the anything I can do to make the Ubuntu installer recognize the windows 7 install?

Comment: Was drive gpt before? If so Windows 7 installer does not correctly convert to MBR, it leaves backup gpt partition table. YOu have to use fixparts to remove it. http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/  Did you review if any of the other possible issues from rodsbooks site on missing partitions?

Comment: So my computer (Travelmate P645) came with Windows 7 installed, but it also had Windows 8 installation files in a partition. I never actually installed Windows 8 and instead formatted and deleted that partition. I did use fixparts and it runs without an issue with the exception of "Warning:0xEE partition doesn't start on sector 1. This can cause problems in some OSes" but that doesn't seem to solve my problem. I did try to look at other possible issues but I don't  seem to be able to find a solution in them.

Comment: Another symptom that may help in diagnosing the cause: I use diskmgmt on Windows to shrink the default partition and force Ubuntu to install on that partition even if it's not recognizing Windows. During the first reboot, Grub doesn't recognize Windows 7 but after I run `sudo os-prober` it sees the Windows install. I then run `sudo update-grub` and then restart. Grub now recognizes Windows but now Windows doesn't recognize any USB device (even flash drives) plugged in. It was working fine before the Ubuntu install. Could this be somehow related?

Comment: Should not be related. Did you change any settings in UEFI/BIOS? That often controls what hardware works.

Comment: I haven't. But I did check the BIOS and it seems like it's using Legacy Boot instead of UEFI.